# Creating new JPA Entities,no Schemas listed

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, entities

I've a problem with creating JPA Entities. I have a connection to a local MySQL DB and the ping worked fine in the Eclipse Wizard.

I used this [description from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15315_09/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.orm.doc/html/files/genJPAEntities.html) and the [Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) from MySQL

Now I wanted to create new Entities with the Wizard but there aren't any Schemas listed (see link at point 3).

[image]

Is there something wrong with my DB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you select the correct DB Connection in the wizard? Also do you have any schema/table in your DB?

Comment: yes there are three tables in my db